# Spring Boot OAuth2RestTemplate and HTTP Client Metrics

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, resttemplate, spring-micrometer, oauth2resttemplate

Actuator manages the instrumentation of `RestTemplate`, we only have to inject `RestTemplateBuilder` to create `RestTemplate` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class HttpClientConfiguration {
    private final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    // let Actuator manages the instrumentation
    public HttpClientConfiguration(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder;
    }

    @Bean // let Sleuth intercept requests
    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

How to create an `OAuth2RestTemplate` bean (built-in OAuth2) with the HTTP Client Mertics support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuthClientConfig {
    private final MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer metricsRestTemplateCustomizer;

    public OAuthConfig(MetricsRestTemplateCustomizer metricsRestTemplateCustomizer) {
        this.metricsRestTemplateCustomizer=metricsRestTemplateCustomizer;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate createOAuth2RestTemplate() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(
                getClientCredentialsResourceDetails(), 
                new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());
        metricsRestTemplateCustomizer.customize(restTemplate);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    private ClientCredentialsResourceDetails getClientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails rd = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        rd.setClientId("my-client-id");
        rd.setClientSecret("my-client-secret");
        rd.setAccessTokenUri("https://my-idp.server/oauth2/token");
        return rd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I was looking for something similar and found an alertnaive way.

The Spring Boot configured RestTemplateBuilder adds more than just the HTTP Client Mertics (see [RestTemplateAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/client/RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.java)). If you don't want to lose those, you can still use the auto-configured RestTemplateBuilder to configure your OAuth2RestTemplate as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuthClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate createOAuth2RestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        // Create and setup your OAuth2RestTemplate:
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(....);
        
        // let the auto-configure builder configure your template:
        return builder.configure(restTemplate);
    }
}
```